# IcedJava: socket with null address in provided JUnit tests

Tags: sockets, ice

I am trying to use [IcedJava](http://java.net/projects/siptools/pages/IcedJava), and started by running the provided JUnit tests.
The ones in the subpackages *package.attribute* and *stun* seem to run perfectly, but IcePeerTest, StreamingTest and IcedRTPConnectorTest from the *ice* subpackage don't work: this happens because the method getLocalAddress() from class DatagramStunSocket returns a null value. The IceSockets created from objects of type javax.sdp.Media are not bound to any address.
I am running the latest version of IcedJava from the mercurial repository.

Did I do something wrong ? Or did I miss a step ?

I can provide additional details if needed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Keep in mind IcedJava has not been edited in 4 years...